How do you validate that a Java Transactional annotation has been handled?
I have an interface for which I want to implement a Transactional variant.
public interface Service {
    void handle(Object message) throws Exception;
}

My implementation uses an annotation to indicate a transaction is required.
In it's simplest form that would be
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;

public class TransactionalService implements Service {
    private final Service delegate;

    public TransactionalService(Service delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
    @Override
    public void handle(Object message) throws Exception {
        this.delegate.handle(message);
    }
}

How can I validate that the annotation is honored? Is there a simpler way than to check with the TransactionManager? It feels like I'm doing double work.
import jakarta.transaction.Transaction;
import jakarta.transaction.TransactionManager;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;

public class TransactionalService implements Service {
    private final TransactionManager transactionManager;
    private final Service delegate;

    public TransactionalService(TransactionManager transactionManager, Service delegate) {
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
    @Override
    public void handle(Object message) throws Exception {
        Transaction transaction = transactionManager.getTransaction();
        if (transaction != null) {
            this.delegate.handle(message);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No transaction in current thread " + Thread.currentThread());
        }
    }
}


The question belies a more fundamental issue. Let me ask a different question. When you write int a = b + c; how do you check that the compiler and runtime did what you asked it to do? I assume your answer would be: "I.. don't, that's nuts". Which it is. So why are you checking that here? The way these things are set up, you can't call that method without having an instance of TransactionalService which isn't all that easy to do - that constructor takes arguments. (And if the framework calls that method, you have to trust that it 'works', or go debug your deps).

I don't want to verify that the annotation behaves as designed. I want to know that it has been handled by a JTA implementation. In other words: the runtime should not be without JTA handler

I thought you just wanted an answer to How can I validate that the annotation is honored?

I know it's not quite what you asked for but why not write a unit test that implements the Service/handler (this.delegate.handle(message);) and check with the transaction manager there. Maybe you already have tests that validate that the TransactionService has been configured correctly so such a simple test will be enough to validate that the annotation is being respected.

Thanks for the effort, but it's not quite that. I don't want to validate that a JTA implementation handles the annotation. I want to ensure that the TransactionalService coexists with a JTA implementation. Else it would just be a delegating service
